# RoBERTa example from tfhub produces error "During Variant Host->Device Copy: non-DMA-copy attempted of tensor type: string"

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub, invalid-argument

I would like to use the `roberta-base` model from tfhub. I am trying to run the [example below](https://tfhub.dev/jeongukjae/roberta_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1), although I get an error when I try to feed `sentences` to `model` as input. I get the following error `Invalid argument: During Variant Host->Device Copy: non-DMA-copy attempted of tensor type: string`. I am using python 3.7, tensorflow 2.5, and tensorflow_hub 0.12.

If I try to replace preprocessor and encoder with the corresponding BERT versions, the code above works. However, I would like it to work for RoBERTa as well (as shown below).

```
preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4", trainable=True)
```

```
# define a text embedding model
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string)
preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/jeongukjae/roberta_en_cased_preprocess/1")
encoder_inputs = preprocessor(text_input)

encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/jeongukjae/roberta_en_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", trainable=True)
encoder_outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
pooled_output = encoder_outputs["pooled_output"]      # [batch_size, 768].
sequence_output = encoder_outputs["sequence_output"]  # [batch_size, seq_length, 768].

model = tf.keras.Model(text_input, pooled_output)

# You can embed your sentences as follows
sentences = tf.constant(["(your text here)"])
print(model(sentences))
```

[image]

Additionally, the code above with the RoBERTa preprocessor/encoder seems to work if I use CPU instead of GPU (adding with tf.device('/cpu:0')), but this is not feasible because I need to fine-tune a model on lots of data.